# If $f \in C([-1,1])$ is an even function, then the Fourier coefficients $b_n = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-series

The two solutions that are available as of now involve the complex form of solving for the Fourier Coefficient. I want to use the inner product.

**Attempt:**

Given that $f(x)$ is even this means $f(-x) = f(x)$.

Therefore: $$<f(x), \sin(\pi nx)>_{L^2} = \int_{-1}^{1}f(-x)sin(\pi n x)dx \Rightarrow \int_{-1}^{1}f(x)sin(\pi n x) $$.

And this is where I'm stuck. I feel that there is most likely a property of integration that I'm not using. But perhaps there is more.

Comment: $\int_{-1}^1 f(x)\sin(\pi nx)dx = 0$, because we are integrating an odd function.

Comment: Is there something I could read that expands on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the change of variable $y=-x$. Then you get:

$$\begin{aligned}
\int_{-1}^1f(x)\sin(n\pi x)\,dx&=\int_{1}^{-1}f(-y)\sin(-n\pi y)(-dy)=\int_{-1}^1f(y)\sin(-n\pi y)\,dy\\
&=-\int_{-1}^1f(x)\sin(n\pi x)\,dx
\end{aligned}$$

hence the integral equals zero.

Comment: Why is the integral Zero?, Jakobian mentioned it above, but I didn't get somewhere to clarify that.

Comment: The integral is zero because it is a number, say, $A$, satisfying the equation $A=-A$. As it happens, zero is the only solution of this equation in the field of real (or complex) numbers.